# $10$-sheeted covering of $S^1 \times S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does there exists a $10$-sheeted covering of $S^1 \times S^2$.
I think so, the Galois Correspondence for covering map show that there is a covering space with fundamental group $10 \mathbb{Z}$ and this is actually an index $10$ subgroup,  so I can conclude that such a $10$ sheeted covering space exists.

Is it sufficent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a correct argument, but such a cover is also not hard to describe explicitly. If $p \colon S^1 \to S^1$ is a $10$-sheeted cover, then so is $(p \times \mathrm{id}) \colon S^1 \times S^2 \to S^1 \times S^2$.